# AspxGridView: How to reduce spacing between columns in Edit Form?

Tags: devexpress

I am using DevExpress v 2010.2. I have an ASP.NET Web application with an AspxGridView grid control.
I have the following problem with its Edit Form: space between its columns (the controls are located in 2 columns) is too large.

Can I reduce the spacing somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Use recommendations from [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q406165.aspx) DX KB Article to achieve this task.